# Move files using mouse only?

Tags: file

On Windows, you can drag and drop the file using right mouse button, and choose Copy or Move. Moving a file is a very basic computing need.

I cannot find any way to do that on OS X without using the keyboard. Is it possible to move files using mouse only?

Comment: But drag'n'drop works as **Move** not as **Copy** in Finder. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, but only if the source and the destination are on the same volume. I want to explicitly specify "Move" whether it is the same volume or not.

Comment: This is not a very good answer, but off the top of my head, if you were truly restricted to using only the mouse and no keyboard, you can drag the icon from source volume to destination volume, allow the copy to complete, then drag the original to the trash and pull down the menu choice to "Empty the trash."   Again, not very satisfying answer, but it would work.

Answer (score 1):

Aren't you still talking about drag and drop? If you are trying to move something from one Directory in Finder to another, you can drag the file out of the current directory and into the directory on the side bar. For example, if you have text.txt in Documents, and you want to move it to the desktop, you can drag it to Desktop in the sidebar, and it will place the file on the desktop.

Comment: The original poster's issue is that if the source location and destination location are on different volumes, this will create a copy, not a "move".  You can hold down a modifier key on the keyboard to force a "move" operation, but the OP prefers not to use the keyboard.